# Route certain domains through cloudflare warp

Tags: networking, cloudflare, www

I'm new to this subject. I have a ubuntu vps and vnc server installed on it. I want to use cloudflare warp only for selected domains/subdomains and all other traffic go through default WAN interface. Trying to unblock 2 websites with it's subdomains. I have already tried cloudflare warp. There's a option to exclude a domain. But it's not practical to exclude all other domains while selected domains go through warp. Also installed Wireguard, but it is very complicated for me to understand.

Cloudflare WARP
https://1.1.1.1/
https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare does offer what you want for your specific setup, but it's not under thair WARP/1.1.1.1 program offering.

They have another version called [Zero Trust](https://www.cloudflare.com/zero-trust/), which has a free plan. It offers the same features as before, with more added.

The mode that describes what you want is called "Split Tunnels" with a different mode for "Include" based rules instead of excluding. Turns it into a whitelist of domains you want WARP to service, rather than the Exclude/blacklist mode you are stuck with now.

- ["Configure Split Tunnels"](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-devices/warp/configure-warp/route-traffic/split-tunnels/) documentation
- [CloudFlare community thread](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-exclude-tunnel-specific-domains-apps-1-1-1-1-warp-windows-10/438431/4) asking the same question as you, with responses and answers.

It's late, but I hope this helps you and anyone else who stumbles into this.